# How do I use the SIGALRM correctly?

Tags: c

I'm made this code, and I have to use the alarm signal (`SIGALRM`) to make the program print the message “I am alive.” every 3 seconds.

But it doesn't work, it sends the message "I'm Alive" only when I press CTR-C, I'm guessing
I didn't put the SIGALRM function in the right place, can you help me?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

unsigned Count = 0; //Counts the number of times it receives the signal SIGINT.
void mypause(int sign); //prototype of the function my pause.

void mypause(int sign) {
  signal(SIGALRM, mypause); //Set alarm clock for 3 seconds.
  alarm(3);
  printf("I'm Alive");
  signal(SIGINT, mypause);
  switch (sign) {
  case SIGINT:
    printf("\nPressed CTR-C\n");
    printf("I'm running, waiting for a sign\n");
    Count++;
    break;
  case SIGQUIT:
    printf("\nPressed CTR-\\n");
    printf("You pressed CTR-C %d times", Conta);
    exit(0); //Exit program.
    break;
  }
}

int main() {
  signal(SIGALRM, mypause);
  signal(SIGINT, mypause);
  signal(SIGQUIT, mypause);
  printf("\nI'm running waiting for a signal\n");
  while (1) {}
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Note: you should not use printf() inside a signal handler; it is non-reentrant.

Comment: @wildplasser so I should put the printf("I'm Alive) in the int main()???

Comment: You can put the printf()s anywhere, but *not in the signal handler*. It *could* work, but someday it may explode in your face. Be prepared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe add `alarm(3)` in your `main()` ?

Comment: Link to docs: http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm